# How to get horizontal scroll offset on dynamically created element?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, scroll, element

I am fixing some content mistakes and I need to make sure that all wide tables are scrollable horizontally. I can find them, no problem, but I can't get scroll offset.

I create an element (wrap a table) and bind custom event handler like this (I suspect this is the only way for dynamically created elements to capture scroll):

`$(this)` refers a `table`needed to be wrapped

```
$(this)
  .wrap('<div class="responsive-table-nav-wrapper left right"/>')
  .wrap('<div class="responsive-table-wrapper"/>')
  .parent()
  .bindScrollHandler1();
```

Here is the function that handles event:

```
$.fn.bindScrollHandler1 = function() {
  $(this).on('scroll', function() {
    console.log($('responsive-table-wrapper').scrollLeft());
  });
};
```

The function is firing, I do see an event attached in browser Code Inspector, but I am getting `null` in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo in the selector as you're missing the class prefix: `$('responsive-table-wrapper')` needs to be `$('.responsive-table-wrapper')`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Also note that hard-coding selectors in a jQuery plugin is a bad idea. Make the selector traverse the DOM from the element which the plugin was instantiated on

Comment: Jesus...... Damn, thanks :) Yes, it's typo, my bad.